# Node stops responding after a while

Tags: node.js

My node server is running normally. Working with absolutely no issues.
Then at a certain (random?) point in time, it stops responding to requests. 
(It did respond for hours uninterrupted before.)

There are no errors. The server is still able to do internal processes, but is not responding to requests.

With that, the requests are making their way to the server as the log shows:

```
GET / - - ms - -
GET / - - ms - -
GET /upload - - ms - -
GET /profile - - ms - -
```

I can't figure out when it is triggered, what is happening, and why it's happening.

Once the server stopped responding, it will never respond again. Restarting the server solves the issue until it happens again.

Anybody ever encountered this behavior?

**Update:**

1. The server never crashes, just stops responding.
2. This app is over a year old, and was working fine, so I doubt it's a basic, but rather something else.
3. Recent change: Started using YouTube SPF
4. Recent change: Connecting to a MongoDB on a remote server rather than localhost

Again, the server never crashes, just stop responding.

**These are the components I am using for the server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParse = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var configDB = require('./config/database');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var https = require("https");
var path = require('path');
var helmet = require ("helmet");
var robots = require("express-robots");
var Sitemap = require('sitemap')
var async = require('async')
var cron = require('node-schedule');
var compression = require('compression')
```

**Update:**

**Added annotated pm2 logs:**

```
0|server   | GET /public/js/fullscreen.js 304 72.626 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/js/mathUtils.js 304 72.291 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/js/snap.svg.js 304 74.047 ms - -
0|server   | GET /views/58dc059bf5ac4394447e7a4d/82z7rw8qbvgqfr 304 95.918 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/js/playerTransport.js 304 96.425 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/rightarrow.png 304 82.923 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/BecomicsLogo.png 304 93.323 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/leftarrow.png 304 84.158 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/fullscreen.png 304 93.776 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/fonts/foundation-icons.woff 304 61.611 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png 404 57.253 ms - 39
0|server   | GET /public/images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png 404 57.646 ms - 39
0|server   | POST /rating/get 200 111.758 ms - 37
0|server   | POST /player/getBook?id=58dc059bf5ac4394447e7a4d 200 99.961 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/loading.gif 304 70.614 ms - -
0|server   | POST /stats/pageView 200 73.545 ms - 2
0|server   | GET /subscriptions 304 655.215 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/css/discover.css 304 72.171 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/css/becomics.css 304 73.344 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/js/spf.js 304 65.621 ms - -
0|server   | GET /public/res/img/hamburgerMenu.png 304 58.525 ms - -


0|server   | POST /subscriptions/count 200 111.033 ms - 11 <--- This is the last time the server will respond
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694/$otherUserPic - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694/$picTheWhat - - ms - -


0|server   | So far so good <--This prints just before the res.send(). It verifies that the request makes it all the way to the response. But still. No response... 
0|server   | So far so good
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694/$otherUserPic - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694/$picTheWhat - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /subscriptions - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694 - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694 - - ms - -

0|server   | Counting Views. <--- this is a croned operation. It executes with no problem. Even after server stopped responding.
0|server   | GET /profile/5825063e47234fc77cbc7694 - - ms - -
0|server   | GET / - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /profile/5806a8116b9b49b4201f5487 - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /trendy?spf=navigate - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /trendy?spf=navigate - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /fresh?spf=navigate - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /series/58dc032ef5ac4394447e7a3c - - ms - -
0|server   | GET / - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /featured?spf=navigate - - ms - -
0|server   | GET / - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /featured - - ms - -
0|server   | GET / - - ms - -
0|server   | GET /ping - - ms - -
```

As you can see. No errors. Any ideas?

**Also note** that /ping is a route that is just supposed to return status 200. No db querying, no nothing. The simplest response possible, and that fails too.

**Update**
Tried using different browser + chrome's incognito to verify that it is not a cache issue. Still no response.

**PM2 Monit**:

```
Mem: 140MB CPU:0%
Loop delay 1.46ms
```

**CPU Profile:**

[image: CPU Profile]

**Heap snapshot**

[image]

**Update 4/2/2017:**
After some debugging I think it has to do with a disconnect from the remote server... Once I resolve this I will post answer.

**Update 4/3/2017**
Here is my mongooose connect code:

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url,{user:configDB.user,pass:configDB.pwd,server:{reconnectTries:60,reconnectInterval:1000}});
// CONNECTION EVENTS
// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + configDB.url);
});

// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
    console.log("Disconnecting")
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
// When the connection is disconnected
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
    //It automatically reconnects with not issues
});
```

The thing is, non of these listeners fire when my problem occurs. No errors or exceptions thrown. No disconnect triggered. Just Halts..

Comment: Do you use mysql?

Comment: I am using MongoDB, and croned mongo processes are executed successfully

Comment: Are you using mysql also ?

Comment: I am not using mysql at all.

Comment: It seems node server take some requests and after that it stops the TCP connection, It could be you are using something like pooling connection and not releasing that connection, this is my personal experience

Comment: Since there is little information to go on, I would suggest trying [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) on your node app then when the server stops and restarts look at the logs to see what was going on.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich how are you setting up the connection to MongoDB? How do you share it among requests?

Comment: @robertklep I am using  Mongoose with mongostore. Can you be a little more specific with your question? I don't know where to start

Comment: If you're using Mongoose, you most likely aren't setting up database connections manually (I assume you use `mongoose.connect(...)` somewhere), so I don't think it'll be related to connections not being returned to the pool. Do you have any global error handling that may be swallowing any errors that are being generated?

Comment: @twg Installed PM2, I'll update with some insights hopefully. Anything specific that I should look for?

Comment: Show your code. It's a bit like hunting in the dark w/o it.

Comment: @Paul what of my 32,000 lines of code should I show? I don't know where to even start investigating.

Comment: Any that have changed around the time that the problem started would be a good start.

Comment: @twg Added pm2 Logs. Anything specific I should attach?

Comment: I had this error on dev server. It is because of a syntax error inside a specific route, the route handler was designed using bluebird promise. When I restart the server, everything will be fine till I hit that route, after that every response just dissapper and the Morgan simply logs --. Try to find out which route is causing the problem, and debug it thoroughly.

Comment: As @robertklep suggested, some error handlers might be swallowing the error and unbalancing the express.

Comment: @NidhinDavid Was just able to access all the routes included in my previous (faulty) log (same credentials and paths). And the server is still serving. I suspect it's not a faulty route after all.

Comment: Also I made sure that all the errors are thrown, but no errors are showing...

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich I would check if your Mongo (which you moved to a remote server) is going down. You may not have configured it correctly or it may be going down due to a variety of issues in configuration, pooling and memory usage. That may be the source of the problem and the disconnects.

Comment: What I tried to do is cause the server to output errors on purpose, and I get Exceptions thrown (great!), same if I disconnect the internet, I get my on('disconnect') listener to fire. 
But non of these happen (Exception, nor listener), when my problem occurs... See update

Comment: I suspect that your request is getting hung up in the session middleware. If you delete your cookies will the request come through when it is in a stalled state?

Comment: Did you get explanation or logs that could identify the problem? I have the same issue with my express/mongo server.

Comment: Was never able to identify the problem... Still suffering from it...

Comment: Any solution for above because I am facing the same Issue :(

Comment: Any answers for this? I have the same issue with the same setup.  Ran for 6 months no issue, then stopped responding without crashing the server.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich Did you find a solution for your problem. For a month now we have a similiar issue but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not..

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you could share your code so that we're more clear about the problem.

If you're using express, It could simply be the wrong ordering of app.use , or its possible that you have a faulty middleware. You can use a debugger or just find out on which requests your server crashes and give it a fix .

Comment: This is an app that has been running for 2 years, with dozens of routes. Hard to share code when I don't know where the problem is. Also, the server never crashes

Comment: Alright in that case there are two things that I can think of after your update. 1) problem with remote MongoDB server 2) your server might have been overwhelmed. Do you have a lot of users ?

Comment: I doubt that is has anything to do with MongoDB because even a request static paths, returns nothing. /image.jpg or /faq

Comment: because you said the server has been running for over a year without a problem which means either you added something new that's causing the problem or your system is not tolerant.try going back to an old commit ( if you have one) and see if it solve the problem.

Comment: I am also facing same issue ,  some times i got `malloc(): Unsorted double linked list`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact same issue.
My problem was that I had transactions which were not committed or rollback. So, they were open probably causing a lock on resources after a point.

Answer (score 0):

In my case we had a similar issue and it was the duplicate getDb and getConnection. I hope it might help someone.

```
router.get("/getData", checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const pool = getDb();
  const connection = await pool.getConnection();

  try {
    const pool = getDb();
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();

    const [rows] = await connection.execute(" SELECT * FROM data");
```

Answer (score -1):

I too faced similar issue, after restarting the system the issue got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

May be your server limit reach please
check your server and increase the limit of server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).